# Using AppleScript to send email message; How do you set the background and font colors?

Tags: macos, applescript, mail.app, email, automation

Using AppleScript to send email message; How do you set the background and font colors?

I have everything working but I can't set the background color??

The font color (is working)

```
set color of words of MyMessage to {65535, 65535, 65535} # white text
```

This is what I been trying for the background and I get a error:

```
set background color of MyMessage to blue
```

and also did

```
set background color of MyMessage to {65535, 65535, 65535}`
```

both did not work.. please help me out

Comment: Or alternatively, you can send an email with html content, that way you can customize it however you want. Check [this](https://macscripter.net/viewtopic.php?id=39914) out!

Answer (score 2):

Background color is a property of a message object.
So you must send the color update command to the message and not to the mail application:

```
tell MyMessage
    set background color to blue
end tel
```